# UWP App Keeps Throwing Unauthorized Access Exception

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, storage

I am making an UWP App and I keep having a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`

Here is the full Code of my main file

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var user = new Configuration();
            string Email = txtEmail.Text.Trim();

                user[Email]["Value"].StringValue = "test";

            string dest = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Users\IT\Desktop\AttendanceApp\AttendanceApp\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\Test\user.cfg");
            user.SaveToFile(dest);
        }
```

As I was reading the documentation for File Access Permission for UWP apps, it had suggested to add this line

> xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
>   IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp uap5 rescap"> ...

And this is my AppxManifest file

```
<Package xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp uap5 rescap" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" xmlns:uap5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/5">
---
  <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
  </Capabilities>
```

So when I try to save a file. I still keep having this error.

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException   HResult=0x80070005
>   Message=Access to the path
>   'C:\Users\IT\Desktop\AttendanceApp\AttendanceApp\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\Test\user.cfg'
>   is denied.   Source=System.Private.CoreLib   StackTrace:    at
>   System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare
>   share, FileOptions options)    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options)    at
>   SharpConfig.Configuration.SaveToFile(String filename, Encoding
>   encoding)    at SharpConfig.Configuration.SaveToFile(String filename) 
>   at AttendanceApp.MainPage.SaveButton_Click(Object sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\IT\Desktop\AttendanceApp\AttendanceApp\MainPage.xaml.cs:line
>   57

By the way I am also using `SharpConfig` to edit my `.cfg` files

Any ideas why this happens? Any help would be great

Comment: Have you checked if you can create / access that file manually?  Also, I'm guessing you're running in VS - are you running VS as admin?

Comment: @pm_2 I can access the file because I created It, I'll give that a try

Comment: @pm_2 tried running VS as administrator, the problem still occurs

Comment: @newboooooo: Restricted capability is configurable by the user. Check your current settings under Settings->Privacy.

Comment: @mm8 I already did, but I still have the problem

Comment: @newboooooo: It seems like you are trying to write to the same directory as your exe. This is not supported. Try another directory.

Comment: You can try using `FullTrustProcessLauncher` as described here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher

Comment: Alternatively you should have no problem accessing a known `StorageFolder`. i.e. `StorageFolder LocalFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;`

Comment: Did you check `Settings > Privacy > File system.` and see if it is enabled?

Comment: @mm8 i tried accessing from the desktop and drive D: but I still have the same problem

Comment: @AdamMcMahon tried having the `FullTrustProcessLauncher` but I still have the error

Comment: @AVK I did already allow it, but the error still occurs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two places you need to be aware of：

1. As @mm8 said, the path in your above code `C:\Users\IT\Desktop\AttendanceApp\AttendanceApp\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\` equals `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path`. In UWP, the installed localtion folder is read-only. You cannot use any APIs to write in it. You could think about coping 'user.cfg' to other place, then you could write to it. The [ApplicationData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata) folder would be a good choice. For example, [LocalFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalFolder).
2. I saw that you add the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability to access files outside the app cantainer. That's great, but you missed an [important prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations) **'This capability works for APIs in the [Windows.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage) namespace.'**. I've checked the SharpConfig's source code, the [SaveToFile](https://github.com/cemdervis/SharpConfig/blob/771519c745fd9ef816c5709373f795c55abb0749/SharpConfigShared/Configuration.cs#L484) method uses the 'FileStream' relevant APIs to write file. It's not included in 'Windows.Storage Namespace'. So, the 'broadFileSystemAccess' capanility doesn't work for it.

So, if you have to use 'SharpConfig' in your project, you need to use the 'Windows.Storage Namespace' APIs to change its source code and compile a custom version for your UWP project. In the meantime, keep in mind my explanation in the first paragraph.